# Where can I find OED articles on various phonemes' pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

Dear ladies and gentlemen. I found myself in need of a detailed source of information regarding variants of pronouncing English sounds, and chanced upon this answer presented by **tchrist** several years ago:

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77118/262320

The information given in this reply is exactly the kind I was looking for, however for the life of me I can't find either the original OED article or even the exact edition of OED where such detailed information on pronunciation is present. I would love to ask **tchrist** directly, however the site won't allow that. Could you please help me?

Best regards,

Xaenor

Comment: @tchrist can you answer this request directly?

Comment: You can always ask in chat (he is a mod)

Comment: @Mitch, thanks! Sadly, I think my reputation is not high enough to talk in the chat :( It says I need at least 20, and I only just registered and am still learning the ropes.

Comment: By "variants", are you talking more about differences between different accents, or the way that the "same" sound can be pronounced differently depending on the influence of the surrounding sounds (e.g. people pronouncing the "i" in "stink" differently from the "i" in "stint")?

Comment: @sumelic, the second one. Basically, I want to have a comprehensive, end-to-end picture of English phonemes and phonemic distribution, inlcuding, if possible, rules and patterns that hint at the ways of pronunciation depending on the surrounding letters. Exceptions would also be helpful, be it due to historic development or as a result of borrowings. That's why tchrist's answer in that old thread is so valuable to me - it cites a lot of "less than obvious" cases while also providing phonetic representations of the said sounds from IPA.

Comment: Your request could be taken as desiring an thorough explanation of English phonology. This would probably require a book length treatment (e.g. Chomsky and Halle's 'The Sound Patterns of English', or a pronunciation guide for teachers of English as a foreign language). Most published paper editions of dictionaries have preface material about pronunciation and grammar of English that might not be comprehensive enough for a language learner, but they'll go in the direction of tchrist's quote.

Comment: Well, every English phonologist would like the same thing; that's what they're all looking for. But it's a work in progress, and the real detail work is being done by sociolinguists, who correlate the variations with social and pragmatic factors. It's not just the phonemes and their variants -- it's the range and characteristics of their contexts that must be considered.

Comment: Well,  Wikipedia has an article giving an overview of [English phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology), and for an overview of sound-spelling correspondences, you can read the book "[Dictionary of the British English Spelling System](http://books.openedition.org/obp/2174)", by Greg Brooks.

Comment: @sumelic, thanks a ton for that Dictionary - it's a wonderful book and I think it'll serve me just fine. If you like, please leave an answer with the link to it so that I can mark your reply as the answer I was looking for.